# Add a new Header to Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, http, http-headers, httpresponse

How can I add a new header to an   **org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity** object ?

Here is my code:

```
public void addCustomHeader(ResponseEntity response,String headerName,String headerValue)
{
  response.getHeaders().add(headerName, headerValue);
}
```

when I try the above code, I get

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: The `ResponseEntity` is immutable you would have to create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

ResponseEntity.getHeaders() returns you the immutable object and hence if you attempt to update it you get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

So, you have to create a new copy of headers and populated the existing headers and add the new required headers on top of it. And finally attach the headers to the ResponseEntity.

```
 //create a new headers object.
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //add all existing headers in new headers
     headers.addAll(response.getHeaders()); 
    //add the new required header
    headers.add("newheader","newvalue"); 
    //add the headers to the responseEntity along with yourBody object
    ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(headers).body(yourBody);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need create a now one.

```
   final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   responseHeaders.set(headerName, headerValue);
   final ResponseEntity<> response = new ResponseEntity<>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest you to implement:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get-products-detail/", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProductsDetail(@RequestParam Long userToken, @RequestParam Long productId) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(digitoonContentService.getProductsDetails(userToken, productId));
        } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
            logger.info("token is null or invalid", e);
            MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("invalid_token", "true");
            ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorDTO, headers, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a copy of your `ResponseEntity`. Unfortunately `HttpHeaders` are read-only. But there is a helpful method that "converts" (it makes a copy if HttpHeaders is read-only) read-only `HttpHeaders` into writeable `HttpHeaders`. `HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders headers)`

```java
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> addCustomHeader(ResponseEntity<T> response, String headerName, String headerValue) {
  HttpHeaders headers = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(response.getHeaders());
  headers.add(headerName, headerValue);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), headers, response.getStatusCode());
}
```